# What is api to manage taskbar?

Tags: android

From Android 12L we have taskbar present as part of navigationbar.

1. Do we have api to detect if it is currently present(as it can be hidden)? Plain listening to insets does not works, as gesture line or 3 button navigations are already propagating insets. I need to know taskbar state
2. How to change it color? I found that window.navigationBarColor = controlColor does not wor on some divices.
3. any other api related task bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no direct API to manage the taskbar in Android 12L. While the taskbar is part of the navigation bar, it is not exposed through separate APIs. This means that there is no way to explicitly control its visibility or colour. Regarding detecting the taskbar's presence, you can still rely on the `SystemBarsInsets class` to obtain the insets of the system bars, including the taskbar. However, as you mentioned, this method is not entirely reliable as other navigation bars, such as the gesture navigation bar, also contribute to the insets. Therefore, you may need to implement additional logic to differentiate between the taskbar and other navigation bars based on their position or other characteristics. As for changing the taskbar's colour, using `window.navigationBarColor = controlColor` may not work consistently across devices due to the underlying system implementation. This method is intended for changing the colour of the navigation bar itself, which may not always align with the taskbar's colour. I hope this helps you!